# How to get this achievement?

Tags: java, minecraft

I am trying to get an achievement in a modded server that I play so I went into the source code for the mod posted on github. My problem is that I dont understand what this code is asking me to do.

```
@Override
public void receive(EntityPlayer sender, EntityPlayer clientPlayer, InteractionType type, Side side, int x, int y, int z)
{
    if (side.isServer())
    {
        TileEntity tile = sender.worldObj.getTileEntity(x, y, z);

        if (tile instanceof TileEntitySign)
        {
            TileEntitySign sign = (TileEntitySign) tile;

            for (String s : sign.signText)
            {
                if (s.matches("bAtFiSh|BaTfIsH"))
                {
                    sender.triggerAchievement(SHAchievements.SECRET);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why not ask the code's author?

Comment: its meant to be a secret achievement and the desc of the achievement is "???"

Comment: If you found this on githup, there should be an owner associated with their account. Why can't you just ask them?

Answer (score 1):

You need to place a sign where at least one of the lines of the sign has contents "bAtFiSh" or "BaTfIsH" (case sensitive and without the quotes). Presumably, it's an inside joke of some sort that makes sense to the author of the mod.

Comment: i just tried that with quotes and without and it did nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't play minecraft, but I do code, so we are going to analyze that code.

1. `if (side.isServer())` Checking for server or something
2. `TileEntity tile = sender.worldObj.getTileEntity(x, y, z);` Saving the current position? Meaby.
3. `if (tile instanceof TileEntitySign)` Checking for a type of Tile. A signed Tile or something.
4. `TileEntitySign sign = (TileEntitySign) tile;` Programming stuffs :D.
5. In the next lines, the algorithm search for all signs of the tile

```
for (String s : sign.signText)
    if (s.matches("bAtFiSh|BaTfIsH"))
    {
        sender.triggerAchievement(SHAchievements.SECRET);
        break;
     }
}
```

The key is here: **bAtFiSh|BaTfIsH** if is one of these two, *bAtFiSh* or *baTfIsH* you get your achivement.

PD: I hove this is a motivation to start learning programming.